# My slime-repl is not working in ClojureBox

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, clojurebox

I installed ClojureBox and the REPL is not working.

If I type `(+ 1 2)` into the `*slime-repl clojure*` buffer and press enter, the expression text becomes bold as if it has been evaluated, but there is no result of the evaluation printed on the screen.

Can anyone help me figure out why my REPL is not printing the evaluation results?

Thanks.

Comment: Because clojurebox seems windows only I can't test here. But could you include what <kbd>C-h k RET</kbd> reports? If it's bound to `slime-repl-return' then it's a swank problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking in `*inferior-lisp*` and failing that all other buffers.

The binding of clojure's `*out*` plus emacs slime-swank based capture and redirection of output streams can occasionally make it seem like emacs is swallowing output. (This can get really confusing when output comes from multiple threads - definitely one of the few warts of developing clojure with the slime-swank environment.)

Have you ever tried emacs before using clojurebox? Any left behind .emacs configuration or library paths etc. can interact badly with clojurebox which, in my experience, assumes it is the only installation of emacs going onto a clean system.